# how boost multi_index is implemented

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

I have some difficulties understanding how Boost.MultiIndex is implemented. Lets say I have the following:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
    employee,
    indexed_by<    
        ordered_unique<member<employee, std::string, &employee::name> >,
        ordered_unique<member<employee, int, &employee::age> >
    > 
> employee_set;
```

I imagine that I have one array, `Employee[]`, which actually stores the `employee` objects, and two maps

```
map<std::string, employee*>
map<int, employee*>
```

with name and age as keys. Each map has `employee*` value which points to the stored object in the array. Is this ok?

Comment: `int` is a primitive type. It is not in `std::` namespace.

Comment: Based on the picture [Fig. 1: Diagram of a multi_index_container with three indices](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/multi_index_cont_example.png) at [Boost.MultiIndex Tutorial - Rationale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html), its implementation is just what you imagined.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A short explanation on the underlying structure is given [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/digitalmars-d@puremagic.com/msg33920.html), quoted below:

The implementation is based on nodes interlinked with pointers, just as say your favorite `std::set` implementation. I'll elaborate a bit on this: A `std::set` is usually implemented as an rb-tree where nodes look like

```
struct node
{
  // header
  color      c;
  pointer    parent,left,right;
  // payload
  value_type value;
};
```

Well, a `multi_index_container`'s node is basically a "multinode" with as many headers as indices as well as the payload. For instance, a `multi_index_container` with two so-called ordered indices uses an internal node that looks like

```
struct node
{
  // header index #0
  color      c0;
  pointer    parent0,left0,right0;
  // header index #1
  color      c1;
  pointer    parent1,left1,right2;
  // payload
  value_type value;
};
```

(The reality is more complicated, these nodes are generated through some metaprogramming etc. but you get the idea) [...]

Comment: +1, explains the OP's use case exactly. I wonder if Boost.MultiIndex uses Boost.Intrusive internally?

Comment: No, Boost.MultiIndex does not use Boost.Intrusive, primarily because the former library is older than the latter. A rewrite in terms of Boost.Intrusive would be in principle doable, though.

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz: I know this is an old answer, however it would be great if you could post an excerpt of your e-mail here. The guideline in SO questions and answers is to provide the details *directly* so that link-rotting or offline viewing do not significantly cut down on their values.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, yes.

From what I understand of Boost.MultiIndex (I've used it, but not seen the implementation), your example with two `ordered_unique` indices will indeed create two sorted associative containers (like `std::map`) which store pointers/references/indices into a common set of `employee`s.

In any case, every `employee` is stored only once in the multi-indexed container, whereas a combination of `map<string,employee>` and `map<int,employee>` would store every employee twice.

It may very well be that there is indeed a (dynamic) array inside some multi-indexed containers, but there is [no guarantee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnd_vs_vector) that this is true:

> [Random access indices] do not provide memory contiguity,
>   a property of `std::vector`s by which
>   elements are stored adjacent to one
>   another in a single block of memory.

Also, [Boost.Bimap is based on Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/bimap_and_boost.html#boost_bimap.bimap_and_boost.bimap_and_multiindex) and the former allows for different representations of its "backbone" structure.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I do not think it is.

Based on what is located in `detail/node_type.hpp`. It seems to me that like a `std::map` the node will contain both the value and the index. Except that in this case the various indices differ from one another and thus the node interleaving would actually differ depending on the index you're following.

I am not sure about this though, Boost headers are definitely hard to parse, however it would make sense if you think in term of memory:

- less allocations: faster allocation/deallocation
- better cache locality

I would appreciate a definitive answer though, if anyone knows about the gore.